# Help creating a math word problem.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am needing some help to create a word problem that will be directed to a math teacher, they have asked me how many more copies they can print this month. I would like to make the problem as difficult as possible but it is already exceeding my knowledge :O

The number of remaining copies is 1591.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need a word problem whose answer is $1591$?

Comment: Correct, maybe i should have said that!

Comment: I think some pointer as to what your knowledge is might be helpful in stating a problem.

Comment: Understood Piotr.
Whilst the answer below is correct, I was looking for something that would be more of a challenge to solve

Answer (score 3):

"A teacher is allowed an average of $100$ copies per day over a $30$-day period.  If the teacher has already copied $1409$ times this $30$-day period, how many copies does he have left?"